# Why is Firefox trying to connect to an advertising company?

Tags: privacy, firefox, safe-browsing-filter

My firewall blocked Firefox from connecting to a site with an invalid security certificate. But why would it want to connect to an advertising site in the first place? Isn't Mozzilla and Firefox all about privacy? My firewall blocked Firefox three times now:

> firefox.exe attempted to establish a connection relying on an unmatching security certificate to marketplaces.vantagemedia.com. We blocked the connection to keep your data safe since the used certificate was issued for a different web address than the targeted one.

Comment: Is there some reason you believe this connection is not caused by whichever website you were visiting at the time? Because that's the obvious answer. But it's so obvious as to be non-interesting, so I assume you have a reason to believe that's not the cause?

Comment: Just disabled "Top Sites" and see what happens, as it may preload some content in the background. In fact,  Chrome is even worst as it doesn't allow you to disabled recently visited site by setting. Also check those firefox plugin/addon.  No all "blocker" are blocking stuff that you think.